# MVC date not received correctly in server model

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to edit a value already present in the table. When i click the edit button next to the row of an entry i want the values the original value to be present in the input fields on the form and when i change something it should be edited or else remain same. Now this is working except the date passes a null to the backend controller. i have checked in the debugger.

**View:**

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Date Of Birth </label>
         <div class="col-sm-9">
           <input type="text" id="dob" maxlength="30" ng-model="userAccount.dateOfBirth" class="form-control datepicker required" required>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**Angular.js:**

```
$scope.UserSave = function () {
    debugger
    $scope.userAccount.dateOfBirth = $('#dob').val();
    $scope.userAccount.CountryID = $('#countryoptions').val();

    Post("/User/Change", $scope.userAccount, false, $("#btnSave")).then(function (d) {
        if (d.Success) {
            window.location.href = "/User/LoggedIn";
        }
        ShowMessage(d);

    });
}
```

**Generic.cs:**

```
    function Post(url, data, isBlockUI, e) {
BlockUI(isBlockUI, e);

return $.ajax({
    method: "Post",
    url: url,
    // contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,//JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (d) {
        UnBlockUI(e);
        if ($.type(d) == "string" && d == "")
            LogOutNotification()
        else if ($.type(d) == "string")
            AccessDenied();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        UnBlockUI(e);
        ErrorMessage(errorMsg);
    }
});
```

}

I made a separate function to handle the data sending and recieving from the backend as shown above and i know its working fine because i am adding the data into the database using it.

But now comes my problem. This data is passed to a controller and the data passed is all right except for the date. The date is null and i have no idea why. Since the date field is  set to not null in the db on entering the data it gives me an exception.

**controller:**

```
    public JsonResult Change(Account account) {
        return Json((new userLogic()).Change(account), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

here when debugging i check the value for the account.dateofbirth attribute and its set to 1/1/0001 which from what i know is null in date format. so i get an error when trying to save to the db.

**Logic:**

```
    public Message Change(Account account) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        try
        {
            Account userProfile = db.Accounts.Where(b => b.Email == account.Email).FirstOrDefault();
            var dob = account.dateOfBirth;
            if (userProfile == null)
            {
                msg.Success = false;
                msg.MessageDetail = "somehting went wrong could not find the data entry amke sure the database connection is working";
            }
            else {
                userProfile.firstName = account.firstName;
                userProfile.lastName = account.lastName;
                userProfile.Email = account.Email;
                userProfile.password = account.password;
                userProfile.CountryID = account.CountryID;
                userProfile.dateOfBirth = account.dateOfBirth;
                userProfile.phoneNo = account.phoneNo;

                db.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                msg.Success = true;
                msg.MessageDetail = "Edit successful";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            msg.Success = false;
            msg.MessageDetail = "somehting went wrong could not find the data entry make sure the database connection is working";
        } 
        return msg;
    }
```

I know the problem is somewhere when i send the data of the object to the controller. But i cant seem to find my mistake i am adding the data in a similar way just changing the logic in the backend and it seems to be working fine.

Data from browser Network tab showing what is sent in the AJAX request:

The URL encoded:

```
IsPermissionUpdated: false
UserId: 12
password: 88888888
firstName: Ali
lastName: Shujaat
Email: Ali%40gmail.com
CountryID: 6
phoneNo: 3244183346
dateOfBirth: 28%2F08%2F2018
isActive: true
Country: 
Password: 97533284
```

The URL decoded:

```
IsPermissionUpdated: false
UserId: 12
password: 88888888
firstName: Ali
lastName: Shujaat
Email: Ali@gmail.com
CountryID: 6
phoneNo: 3244183346
dateOfBirth: 28/08/2018
isActive: true
Country: 
Password: 97533284
```

**Code for adding the data: Since i am using the exact same method and it works fine.**

**View:**

```
     <div class="col-sm-12">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Date Of Birth </label>
             <div class="col-sm-9">
               <input type="text" id="dob" maxlength="30" ng-model="userAccount.dateOfBirth" class="form-control datepicker required" required>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

**Angular:**

```
     $scope.UserSave = function () {

    $scope.userAccount.dateOfBirth = $('#dob').val();
    $scope.userAccount.CountryID = $('#countryoptions').val();

    Post("/User/Save",  $scope.userAccount , false, $("#btnSave")).then(function (d) {
        if (d.Success) {

        }
        ShowMessage(d);

    });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public JsonResult Save(Account account) {

        return Json((new userLogic()).Save(account), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  

    }
```

**Logic.cs:**

```
    public Message Save(Account account)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
       // Account userProfile = Static.UserProfile;
        try
        {
            Account foundaccount = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == account.Email);

            if (foundaccount != null)
            {
                msg.Success = false;
                msg.MessageDetail = "Email already exist.";
            }

            else
            {
                Country c1 = db.Countries.Find(account.CountryID);
                Account newaccount = new Account();
                //newaccount.UserId = account.UserId;
                newaccount.firstName = account.firstName;
                newaccount.lastName = account.lastName;
                newaccount.Email = account.Email;
                newaccount.password = account.password;
                newaccount.phoneNo = account.phoneNo;
                newaccount.dateOfBirth = account.dateOfBirth;
                newaccount.CountryID = account.CountryID;
                newaccount.isActive = true;
                //newaccount.Country = c1;
                db.Accounts.Add(newaccount);
                //db.Entry(newaccount).State = EntityState.Added;
                db.SaveChanges();
                msg.MessageDetail = account.Email + "has been saved";    
            }

            //userProfile.LogActivity("Save", msg.MessageDetail, "EmploymentType");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg.Success = false;
            msg.MessageDetail = Message.ErrorMessage;
           // userProfile.LogError(ex, "BLL/EmploymentTypeLogic/Save");
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

**Exception I am getting:**

```
    Message = "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."
```

Comment: What is the format in which the date is sent back? Could you (as a test) just try to send a hardcoded date back in yyyy-mm-dd format?

Comment: dateOfBirth = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: this is the format i ll try out sending a hardcoded date

Comment: no even the hardcoded date is sent as 01/01/0001

Comment: try  `var dob = '2018-01-01';`

Comment: still the same 01/01/0001 date is sent to backend

Comment: you're showing us what the backend object looks like after it has received the data. Now can you show us what is actually being sent by the browser? Look in the browser's Network tool for the AJAX call to the "change" URL... click that request, and you can see in the request body what actual data was _sent_. Tell us what it shows. Then we know for sure that data is being sent correctly or not, and whether it's a case of missing data, or whether the server is not parsing it correctly.

Comment: @ADyson is this what u asked for?
Url Encoded :
IsPermissionUpdated: false
UserId: 12
password: 88888888
firstName: Ali
lastName: Shujaat
Email: Ali%40gmail.com
CountryID: 6
phoneNo: 3244183346
dateOfBirth: 28%2F08%2F2018
isActive: true
Country: 
Password: 97533284

decoded URL data:
IsPermissionUpdated: false
UserId: 12
password: 88888888
firstName: Ali
lastName: Shujaat
Email: Ali@gmail.com
CountryID: 6
phoneNo: 3244183346
dateOfBirth: 28/08/2018
isActive: true
Country: 
Password: 97533284

Comment: i will write this in the answers to make it more readable

Comment: Ok thanks. And what culture is your server set to? Would that culture consider dd/mm/yyyy a valid date format? e.g. it would be valid in the UK but not in the USA. Also, I assume that `Account.dateOfBirth` is a `DateTime` field in C#?

Comment: Actually its a local server and it works because i am adding the data using a similar sort of way. its actually the same exact way, but i am not getting a null date while adding it.

Comment: i added the url data to the question in the end in a more readable format

Comment: You mean it works when you test it using your local machine as the server, but not when you deploy the asp.net code to another server? In that case, as I mentioned, check the culture settings on the server.

Comment: No actually i am working as an intern in a company and so i am not actually deploying this. I am working on the project locally and all the data i work with is done on a local db. So i made a register form to add data and then i made a editing form to edit that data using almost the same thing, only the backend is a bit different. but when adding data the date is perfectly fine on the same local db while when i try to edit it using the same method it is fine only till the angular part as soon as it goes to the back end the value changes to 01/01/0001.

Comment: there must be _some_ difference in the way you're doing it compared to the code which works. Unfortunately I can't see them both so I can't compare what you did.

Comment: i can also add the code for adding the data in case you want to compare

Comment: Firstly can you confirm that `Account.dateOfBirth` is a DateTime field in C#?

Comment: @ADyson yes i did confirm it it is a Datetime datatype.

Comment: oh and thank you for fixing the title and the URL data on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Jao and ADyson had a good idea of what the error was about. The format in which the date was going back to the controller was wrong. Every time i selected a date  of the format dd-mm-yyyy where dd was greater than 13 gave me an error and everything below that worked because the datetime in c# is mm-dd-yyyy. which was why i was getting an error.

```
$scope.UserSave = function () {
    //debugger
    var convertedDate = $('#dob').val();
    var splitdate = convertedDate.split('/');
    var year1 = splitdate[2];
    var month1 = splitdate[1];
    var day1 = splitdate[0];
    var date = month1 + "/" + day1 + "/" + year1;
    $scope.userAccount.dateOfBirth = date;

    $scope.userAccount.CountryID = $('#countryoptions').val();
    Post("/User/Change", $scope.userAccount, false, $("#btnSave")).then(function (d) {
        if (d.Success) {
            window.location.href = "/User/LoggedIn";
        }
        ShowMessage(d);

    });
}
```

formatting the date into mm/dd/yyyy fixes the problem completely. One other thing to note was that first since i was getting the data from the table as json data. Json stores date in a different format, so if in the case i wasn't editing the date field. The format would be completely different and the same exception would be thrown. For that reason formatting the data before displaying it is a better option.